# How to get selected values from combobox which is placed in DataGridView

Tags: c#

I am tring to get selected values from Combobox which is placed in DataGridView using following code

```
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  dgvcmb.HeaderText = "Tran_Mode";
        for (ni = 0; ni < dTable.Rows.Count; ni++)
        {
            dgvcmb.Items.Add(dTable.Rows[ni][1].ToString());
         }

        dgv.Columns.Add(dgvcmb);
        dgv.Columns[5].DisplayIndex = 4;
```

can any one tell me how i can get the value ?

Comment: did you check with the Cell `.Value` part ?

Comment: yes i checked. but its giving error.

Comment: you need to be specific what error and how you are doing that ?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". is the Error am getting. I am trying to get that value as follows      MessageBox.Show(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());

Comment: i know, i have to get this value from dgvcmb. But there is no property which provoids this value.

Comment: I think there is no value selected and `Cells[5].Value` is returning null in your case, debug and check what value appears in this case